# Emacs clojure setup configuration

Tags: emacs, clojure

I am looking for a setup configuration file in order to use Emacs and Clojure.
Something similar to this:
https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure/archive/book1.zip

Comment: Have you considered using Spacemacs http://spacemacs.org/layers/+lang/clojure/README.html ?

Comment: Questions asking for book/library/software/tool recommendations are off-topic here. Plus, from the [same github repo you linked](https://github.com/flyingmachine/emacs-for-clojure)...

Comment: I use https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider

Comment: Also voting to close for being off topic, but also happy to mention that I'm quite happy with cider (haven't tried the others, so can't compare).

Comment: I´ve found a very useful and working youtube video regarding the configuration for beginners.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=efPPh2jUrkg R.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you steer clear of the Clojure for the Brave and True customization file. I am new to Clojure and used that file. It uses extremely old versions of Cider, and when I attempted to fix a bug by updating, nothing would work. Eventually, I had to use

```
Locate emacs
```

in terminal to find every specific location of an emacs related file. To make the story short, my emacs never worked again, I eventually lost control of Nautilus file browser and I thought my computer was going to explode. Anyways.

Instead of a configuration file, I suggest you try Spacemacs. It is easy to [install](http://spacemacs.org/#), and easy to configure. Here are [initial setup](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Blang/clojure) instructions for Clojure, and an [brief introduction manual](https://practicalli.github.io/spacemacs/).

Comment: Hi Aaron, I agree with you, the configuration is still working but a little obsolete, nevertheless it is a good starting point to understand emacs and the Clojure configuration. Thanks R.

Comment: Hi razvan, I thought it was as well, until I tried to upgrade. That was a big issue for me!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some fragments from my [Emacs config](https://github.com/igrishaev/dotfiles/blob/master/.emacs). Just put it into you home directory.

Setting up package sources:

```
;; packages
(setq package-archives
      '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
        ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
        ("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")))

(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
```

List of packages (truncated):

```
(setq my-packages
      '(auto-complete
        cider
        clojure-mode
        paredit))
```

Installing the packages:

```
(dolist (pkg my-packages)
  (unless (package-installed-p pkg)
    (package-install pkg)))
```

Clojure(Script) configuration:

```
;; clojure
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook (lambda () (show-paren-mode 1)))
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'eldoc-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'cider-mode-hook #'imenu-add-menubar-index)
(setq cider-font-lock-dynamically nil)
(setq cider-repl-use-pretty-printing t)

;; clojurescript mode
(add-hook 'clojurescript-mode #'paredit-mode)
(add-hook 'clojurescript-mode #'paredit-mode)
```

Setting up code line numbers:

```
;; Line numbers
(line-number-mode   t)
(global-linum-mode  t)
(column-number-mode t)
(setq linum-format " %d")
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I assume you are using this configuration on a mac, on windows machines the configuration is a little more difficult.